# EF Core 2.2 LoggerFactory not Logging DB commands to Console

Tags: c#, logging, dbcontext, asp.net-core-2.1, ef-core-2.2

I'm trying to implement logging database commands from my `DbContext` to a console window so I can examine the T-SQL queries before they're sent to the database.

I defined an `ILoggerFactory` in my `DbContext`:

```
public class PocContext : DbContext
{
    public static readonly ILoggerFactory MyLoggerFactory = new LoggerFactory(new[]
    {
        new ConsoleLoggerProvider((cat, lvl) =>
            cat == DbLoggerCategory.Database.Command.Name &&
            lvl == LogLevel.Information, true)
    });
```

and added it to the `Startup` services configuration:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ... other config stuff

    services.AddDbContext<PocContext>(options =>
        options
            .UseLoggerFactory(PocContext.MyLoggerFactory)
            .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
            .UseOracle(_configuration.GetConnectionString("Foo"))
    );
```

... from watching @JulieLerman EF Core videos I was expecting a Console window to pop up every time before my `DbContext` issued a T-SQL statement to the database - but for me, nothing happens.  I hit my breakpoints in my `_context.Things.ToList()` or `_context.Things.Find(id)` but no logging window appears, it just shows the error from the database in the browser window.

I tried changing the configuration of the ConsoleLoggerProvider to catch more log events:

```
public class PocContext : DbContext
{
    public static readonly ILoggerFactory MyLoggerFactory = new LoggerFactory(new[]
    {
        new ConsoleLoggerProvider((cat, lvl) => true, true)
    });
```

... but still no console window, at all.  What am I forgetting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Queries are logged to the console *by default*. You don't need to do anything.
2. The console window isn't going to just pop up. You have to be running *in* a console window, and then logs will display there, i.e. `dotnet run MyProject.csproj` at a command line. If you're running in Visual Studio, you won't get a console window, but the console output can be viewed in the Output pane. In the dropdown on that pane, choose "ASP.NET Core Web Server".
3. In all other scenarios (IIS, etc.), logging to console isn't going to do anything for you, as there's no way to see it. You can redirect the output to another logging provider using config. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#log-filtering

Comment: Couple of other points. I was using a console application so that will behave differently than Logging in ASP.NET Core (as note by Chris). Also, the syntax of the logging API that I used there (in EF Core 2.0) changed with EF Core 2.2. I wrote a blog post about it here: http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/logging-in-ef-core-2-2-has-a-simpler-syntax-more-like-asp-net-core/

Comment: HA!  A console app - that explains it!  I didn't notice that, for some reason.